# How can I start pagenumbers, where the first section occurs in LaTex?

Tags: latex

This question is related to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501213/how-can-i-have-my-abstract-at-the-titlepage-in-latex) about having abstract at the titlepage. 
I want to reset the page numbering at the given section.

Comment: In your comment to my answer, you say the numbering starts at 1 in the second page. I thought this was what you wanted to achieve. If not, maybe you could edit your question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having this question closed, how about moving it to tex.stackexchange? It would be very much on-topic on that site.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can also reset page number counter:

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

However, with this technique you get wrong page numbers in Acrobat in the top left page numbers field:

```
\maketitle: 1
\tableofcontents: 2
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}: 1
...
```

Answer (score 60):

I use

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

for everything in the frontmatter and then switch over to

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

for the actual content. With pdftex, the page numbers come out right in the PDF file.

Answer (score 47):

To suppress the page number on the first page, add `\thispagestyle{empty}` after the `\maketitle` command.

The second page of the document will then be numbered "2". If you want this page to be numbered "1", you can add `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after the `\clearpage` command, and this will reset the page number.

Here's a complete minimal example:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\title{My Report}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\ldots
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\section{First Section}
\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have this now: http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/68Yt8JkT
The numbering starts at 1 in the second page.

Comment: I placed \clearpage before the first section and \pagenumbering{arabic} after the first section. This ensures that the blank side of the cover page does not begin at '1'.